# I need ideas on how to set a default printer on web page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, printing

I have Visual Studio 2010 and use vb.net in the Code behind.  My Shipping Dept needs to print to a specific ZEBRA LABEL printer when on a certain web page.

From what I've read, this is not possible via javascript or .net?
I read somewhere that maybe I could create an ActiveX control and then it would allow me to change and set the default printer, is this true? or does anyone have any other ideas on how to do this?  Should I use Ajax (is this possible)?
From what I read, I don't think I can use JavaScript.
I am not familiar with java applets, are they easy to write and to attach to a .net web app?

Comment: I am looking for a similar solution. What did you come up with?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible from Javascript. AJAX is an acronym for "Asynchronous Javascript and XML", and it also can not do what you want.

It seems logical that you might be able to do with an ActiveX control with sufficient permissions, but I don't know the details.

Another option that works is for internet-enabled printers. For example, I have an HP printer (disclaimer: I work for HP), and my printer has an email address. I can then write Ruby scripts that will email direct to my printer.

The Zebra Label printer doesn't seem to be able to do this, but you might be able to achieve something similar with Google Cloudprint: https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/

Comment: Thank you for your response.  We don't use google cloudprint.  I don't mind trying to create an Active X control, we use IE, but I just didn't know if this was the latest way of doing something like this.